# Eggs and CP scaling

Tags: pokemon-go

Wild / hatched Pokemon CP is scaled on the level off the player but for eggs, will the scaling be done at the time I find the egg or at the time I hatch it.

Comment: only a guess but it should be by the time you hatch it

Comment: when you hatch it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that an egg's CP is based on your level **when you found the egg**, not when it hatches. We currently only have anecdotal evidence for this, but there is quite a lot of it, which I'll list at the end.

However, eggs will never hatch pokemon above level 20. This was determined from reading the game's internal data files.

> MaxEggPlayerLevel: 20

---

The following are sources of anecdotal evidence (from Reddit) supporting that it is based on your level when you find the egg. I have yet to find any posts about it *not* being based on when you find the egg.

[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t2mu7/psa_trainer_level_at_finding_an_egg_not_hatching/)
[2](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4snmz4/what_effects_hatched_egg_cp/)
[3](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s78yb/how_is_cp_of_hatched_pokemon_determined/)
[4](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4te00p/cp_of_pokemon_hatching_form_an_egg/)
[5](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4tfzh5/do_pok%C3%A9mon_hatched_from_eggs_tend_to_have_higher/)
[6](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4syxho/hatching_eggs_potential_cp_attached_to_level_when/)
[7](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sua25/i_cleaned_up_that_pok%C3%A9mon_egg_list_thats_been/d5cw6jh)

Comment: `eggs will never hatch with a CP above trainer level 20` - what does that mean?

Comment: As you level up, pokemon you find in the wild will become higher level as well. Pokemon from eggs will hatch at a higher level too, but never above 20. Even if you are level 40, eggs will still only hatch pokemon that are 20.

Comment: either I'm missunderstanding this, or it's incorrect, since I've hatched a CP 139 squirtle, and a 200+ hitmonchan

Comment: I've changed my wording now. I meant pokemon's level will not go above 20, not that their CP won't go above 20.