# Is there a way to know the age of my eggs in Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I'm choosing what egg to hatch next, I want to chose the oldest, because they give the weakest Pokemon (affected by my level when picked up, not when hatched). Is there a way to determine what egg is the oldest I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are placed in order. so the last ones are the oldest. But the CP is determined once you hatch them, not when obtained. so it doesnt matter which you choose to hatch.

Comment: according to [Eggs and CP scaling](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275973/eggs-and-cp-scaling) it is determined by the level when obtained.

Comment: as the post explain, is just anecdotal evidence. As my personal experience i notice that the cp is calculated by the time you hatch it.

Comment: Is there a source confirming that the eggs are ordered by age?

Comment: yeah, hours and hours of playing. is not a difficult thing to notice

Comment: Yeah both of the notes were requests for some more proof apart from "Trust me" ... your "evidence" is not much different than those from the link provided, apart from being 1v7 ...

Comment: @lois6b Other people's hours and hours of playing determine that you are wrong.  https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sua25/i_cleaned_up_that_pok%C3%A9mon_egg_list_thats_been/d5cw6jh

Comment: This is wrong. From personal experience, I've had new 2km eggs slotted into seemingly random spots.